# Array.choose for element of tuple

Tags: f#

Here is my current code:

```
placeId
|> Sql.getEOByPlace
|> Array.map (fun eo -> (eo, getType eo))  // (Item * ItemType option)
|> Array.filter (fun (i, it) -> it.IsSome)
|> Array.map (fun (i, it) -> (i, it.Value) // (Item * ItemType)
```

Is there any way to simplify last three lines of code ?
I need something like `Array.choose`, but for one element of tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could return an `(a * b) option` instead of an `a * b option` and use `Array.choose`:

```
placeId
|> Sql.getEOByPlace
|> Array.choose (fun eo -> (getType eo) |> Option.map (t -> (eo, t)))
```